# Horizontally align form elements in Yesod

Tags: haskell, yesod, yesod-forms

I'm building a form in Yesod that needs to have multiple rows consisting of a single text box and radio buttons.  I'm also using renderBootstrap3.

Right now I have:

```
Form = renderBootstrap3 BootstrapBasicForm $ Params
    <$> aopt textField "Car1Name" Nothing
    <*> areq (radioFieldList colorList) "Car1Color" (Just "red")
    <$> aopt textField "Car2Name" Nothing
    <*> areq (radioFieldList colorList) "Car2Color" (Just "red")
```

The problem is that everything is displayed vertically.  I'd like everything for car 1 on one row, and everything for car 2 on the next row.  How can I do this?

Comment: Have you tried [BootstrapHorizontalForm](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/yesod-form-1.3.11/docs/Yesod-Form-Bootstrap3.html#v:BootstrapHorizontalForm)?

Comment: I saw BootstrapHorizontalForm, but it wasn't immediately clear how to use it in this case.  For instance, would each row be a horizontal form, and would I then combine them with a basic form?  If so, how would I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think<sup>1</sup> that you can't achieve the desired behaviour with `renderBootstrap3` only, since Yesod's Bootstrap 3 module supports three standard form types: basic (form element per row), inline (everything in one row, no labels) and horizontal (label + form element per row). Since you need two form elements per row, programatically, in a single form, I suppose that applying additional class attributes to form elements and styling them with CSS should be the easiest solution.

---

<sup>1</sup> I *think*, since I initiated Bootstrap 3 support with [this article](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/msrdic/bootstrap-3-forms-with-yesod-1), but I'm not sure if anything changed in Bootstrap 3 functionality beyond that. Conveniently, you can see form examples in the example at the bottom, but note that Yesod's Bootstrap 3 support has a slightly different API than in that article.

Comment: How can I add CSS classes to form elements?

Comment: I ended up using an input form with runInputPost and just specifying all the html myself.